# Div hover with css

Tags: html, css

I want to do a div as a link, and to tell user that thats is a link I want to do a hover with a different color. But here's a problem: in my div there is picture and text in two separate divs.

```
div { 
  :hover {
  background-color: light cyan;
}
```

And when I hover with a mouse on a div the result is:
[image]

[image]

But I need the all div to become colored. Can you help me?

Comment: have you tried this `div:hover{background-color: light cyan;}` ?

Comment: Some more code examples would be great. And i suggest you to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cw2gb642/

Comment: Totally valid to wrap an image and text inside actual link `<a>` tag. Why don't you do this?

Comment: Aziz has totally valid point here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert your both div tags in a single div and set a class for some css

`.exampleclass:hover { background-color: light cyan; }`

and use as well as you want.
Otherwise If you want something more from me. 
Then please provide html and css both codes to make changes and more better for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

It was really easy, may be some bag of sass, but when i did `div:hover{backgroun‌​d-color: light cyan;}` it really solve the problem.

Thanks you, jonju.

Comment: If you insist on using a div you might wanna add `cursor: pointer` as well.